# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

```
if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    try {
        $json = @file_get_contents('https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email='.$_POST['email'].'&apiKey='.$key);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
        $json == "";
        echo "URL not found!";
     }
    $endStatus = array();
    if($json!=""){
     $objTest = json_decode($json);
     if($objTest->status ==200){
        for($k=0;$k<sizeof($objTest->socialProfiles);$k++){
            echo "\n found:\n".$objTest->socialProfiles[$k]->url;
            $sql =  getSqlQuery($_POST['email'],$objTest);
            $db->query($sql);

        }
     }
    }else{
        echo "\n";
        echo 'https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email='.$_POST['email'].'&apiKey='.$key;
        echo "\n";

    }
}
```

i will try this code for post email value. but Call to a member function query() on a non-object give me the soluation..

Comment: show us what is the output of `echo $sql;`?

Comment: `$db` is not an object. You're not connected to your db.

Comment: And what if $_POST["email"] is null ? Did you define $db?

Comment: found: https://angel.co/dhaval-jani-1INSERT INTO Results (`id`, `email`, `twitter`, `facebook`, `google`, `youtube`, `linkedin`, `xing`, `pinterest`, `updated`) VALUES (NULL, 'dhavaljani1990@gmail.com', 'https://twitter.com/dhavaljani1990', 'https://www.facebook.com/dhavaljani1990', 'https://plus.google.com/u/0/112507135467621604587', '', '', '', 'http://www.pinterest.com/urtechno/', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Answer (score 1):

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object

**tl;dr: You need to use better readability and start to debug properly**

You are clearly not checking if your `$db` is an established connection...

You can check this by doing:

```
if(!$db)? die("db con don't exist") : "";
```

Not sure what API you're using (PDO,SQL,SQLi ect.) but look at error checking like the *try catch* and `connect_errno`